# google cloud compute have two different logins resolve to same home directory on target system

Tags: linux, google-cloud-platform, ssh

**Can I have two different user accounts log into the same home directory on a compute vm?**

For instance, I have the following:

```
user1@machine1
user2@machine2
```

I would like for user1 and user2 to log into the same home directory.

**Is this possible by modifying the compute vm ssh metadata or with os-login?**

Comment: Yes, that is possible, but you do not want to configure a system that way. You will have permission problems (for example the .ssh folder). Instead, create another directory and make both users members of a group with permission to the directory.

Answer (score 1):

You can also try this step below :

1. (optionally) create a group `groupadd groupname`
2. add both users to the group `for u in user1 user2 ; do usermod -aG groupname $u ; done`
3. set the group as the owner of the directory (and files inside) `chown :groupname /var/www ; chmod -R g+rwX /var/www`